# How to transform scaled data that was used for ANN back to its original form so as to compare the values?

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression

I had a real estate pricing data set in which I used Standard Scalar for the input x values and I used log transformation for the y value (Sale Price) to make it normally distributed. I designed and trained the ANN, and got the y_pred and y_test values, except they are not in the original format obviously. They look like:

```
[9.57050085e-01  1.32188116e+00]
```

etc....

How can I view this concatenated array where I can compare the predicted and actual values side by side but in the sale price orignal format?

Thank you!

Comment: If you took log of sale price, then takeing `exp` would get back to the original scale.

Comment: I tried that too, but I don't think I'm getting any luck with that. For instance, one of the values was -5.26409410e-02, and taking the exponent of that would be 0.948720598.

Comment: One thing you should do is to plot the predicted value against the true value and see if they are correlated enough.  Try taking log scale axis as well,  If they don't seem correlated, then it is not the problem of scale but the prediction model is not trained well.  If they are correlated you have a good chance to figure out how to rescale them.